# How to make column name of query result in UPPERCASE

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

How to make column name of query result in UPPERCASE (Postgres)

```
SELECT USER_NAME, USER_AGE from table;
```

Result

| user_name | user_age |
| --- | --- |
| First | 123 |
| Second | 234 |

Expectation : Result column name to be in uppercase
(**USER_NAME**   **USER_AGE** instead of user_name and user_age).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an alias:

```
SELECT user_name as "USER_NAME", 
       user_age as "USER_AGE" 
from table;
```

For details on how identifiers are treated see [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)